# BottomNavigationView not show icon

Tags: android

I set an icon for BottomNavigationView but it not show .
My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Menu :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_bhxh"
    android:title="@string/main_tab_social_bhxh"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_bhxh"
    android:title="@string/main_tab_social_bhyt"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_bhxh"
    android:title="@string/main_tab_social_news"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

and my program :

If you have any suggest , please tell my know .

Comment: Could you show your drawables for the menu?

Comment: @TiPo I just added my drawable.

Comment: Is it same happened when you use default drawable? Eg: ic_home_black_24dp.xml? If not, you need to supply better images then :)

Comment: when i using default image then it't ok . I don't know what is better images ?
I tried other size : 24 * 24 , 32 * 32 , 48 * 48 but don't show. I export my image by adobe illustrator.

Comment: you are using the app:showAsAction="ifRoom", there is no need of this just remove it

Comment: @HAXM it can't resolve my issue :(

Answer (score 0):

After tried some image with different background , I resolved my issue with icon background color is white .