# BottomNavigationView not showing icons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-bottomnavigationview

I've checked all the other posts I can find on this and can't get the icons to even show in the Design preview but it is showing the navigation bar block in design view (with no text or icons).

I am using a nested linear layout and I have set the icons to appear as white against a darker background tint, but when I set up the action bar and tab icon type, i chose the HOLO_DARK theme so they should have been white anyway (I added the icon tint as white too, just to see if that made a difference).

Here is my xml code for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingVertical="60dp"
    android:text="@string/logintext"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/useremail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:text="@string/user_email"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginemailentryid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:hint="@string/common_signin_button_text"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginpasswordentryid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:minHeight="38dp"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbuttonid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registeroption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="40dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgotpasswordoption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="40dp"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password_option"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_primary"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    app:itemTextColor="#fff"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my navigation menu code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/homenav"
        android:title="@string/homeiconmenu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/scoresnav"
        android:title="@string/scoresiconmenu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_scores"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profilenav"
        android:title="@string/profileiconmenu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:visible="true" />

</menu>
```

Some of the posts I have already checked and tried:

- [Android BottomNavigationView not shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971969/android-bottomnavigationview-not-shows)
- [Bottom Navigation Bar not showing icons or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571500/bottom-navigation-bar-not-showing-icons-or-text)
- [Why my Bottom Navigation View does not show any titles or icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510300/why-my-bottom-navigation-view-does-not-show-any-titles-or-icons)
- [BottomNavigationView not show icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336179/bottomnavigationview-not-show-icon)

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions about the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: @Taylor Remove background property from BottomNavigationView or change itemIconTint and itemTextColor colors other then white.

Comment: What kind of files are the images ic_home, ic_scores , ic_account ? probably they are transparent images, could you open and see the images?

Comment: I did try messing with the itemIconTint and text colors but it for some reason never showed the icons/text.  The files for ic_home, ic_scores, ic_account are clip art in android studio that you can use.  I will see if different icons could work though, I haven't tried that.